# Can't share ethernet connection of college ethernet on Mac - but can do it on windows without problems

Tags: network, wifi, sharing, internet-sharing, 802.1x

I'm trying to share my college dorm ethernet connection of my Mac over the WiFi of the laptop with internet sharing in MacOs. Previously, I used a Windows pc and could switch on "Hotspot" in the windows taskbar pretty easily without configuration or error message.
Now trying to do it on the Mac and results in the error that **I can't share the connection, because it is protected 802.1x and therefore can't be shared.**

I already read other stackexchange posts which only seem to have the answer that it's not advisable to share it and they give no solution (other than using a vpn). I understand that the admins of the network have their objectives, but why was I able to share it on the Windows PC pretty easily, without configuration but can't do it on the Mac?

Comment: What versions of the operating systems are/were you using?

Comment: thank you for your comment! On Windows I used Windows 10, on Mac I'm using Big Sur